# String comparison in if condition of Elasticsearch pipeline doesn't match exact string

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Elasticsearch. 
I have to make a check before to know what pipeline to use, so I've made a pipeline that do the routing, like this :

```
{
  "description": "A pipeline of pipelines for log files",
  "version": 1,
  "processors": [
    {
      "pipeline": {
        "if": """ctx.applicative_code =~ /AFA[@]959[@]333-SERVICE[@]1.0.0.SIG/ """,
        "name": "ged_pipeline"
      }
    },
    {
      "fail": {
        "message": "This pipeline requires applicative_code to be one of: 'AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG'"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To test it, I use the _simulate API :

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/logs_pipeline/_simulate
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "message_log": "127.0.0.1:50613||Download||agent||S0000||PM000||Q||{5C7A4600-C422-4D81-BD02-39072E06F646}",
        "applicative_code": "AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the response is this :

```
 "error" : {
        "root_cause" : [
          {
            "type" : "exception",
            "reason" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.elasticsearch.ingest.common.FailProcessorException: This pipeline requires applicative_code to be one of: 'AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG'",
            "header" : {
              "processor_type" : "fail"
            }
          }
        ],
        "type" : "exception",
        "reason" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.elasticsearch.ingest.common.FailProcessorException: This pipeline requires applicative_code to be one of: 'AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG'",
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "org.elasticsearch.ingest.common.FailProcessorException: This pipeline requires applicative_code to be one of: 'AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG'",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "fail_processor_exception",
            "reason" : "This pipeline requires applicative_code to be one of: 'AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG'"
          }
```

So, it seems that my condition doesn't match.
The reason why i'm using a regex here is that the special character "@" mess up the string comparison. What i've tried so far, in the if condition of the pipeline :

```
"if": """ctx.applicative_code == "AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG" """
```

Result : doesn't work, the @ is interpreted and I can't escape it using \

```
"if": """ctx.applicative_code.compareTo("AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG") """
```

Result : Same thing, the @ is interpreted

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're almost there, but you are misunderstanding how pipelines work. The fact that the first `pipeline` processor is matched and does the job, doesn't prevent the second one (i.e. `fail`) to run. In your above pipeline, both steps always run, hence why you see the error.

What you need to do is to run the `fail` step only if the condition doesn't match (sort of `else` condition), like this:

```
{
  "description": "A pipeline of pipelines for log files",
  "version": 1,
  "processors": [
    {
      "pipeline": {
        "if": """ctx.applicative_code == 'AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG' """,
        "name": "ged_pipeline"
      }
    },
    {
      "fail": {
        "if": """ctx.applicative_code != 'AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG' """,
        "message": "This pipeline requires applicative_code to be one of: 'AFA@959@333-SERVICE@1.0.0.SIG'"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```